# Android onPreviewFrame

Tags: android, base64

i'm trying to get data from onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
and convert it to BASE64,

Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT)

the result given is not convertible to an image
(using some sites like http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

note that data is a signed byte array that contain some negative values (values between -128 to 127), i think it should be array of unsigned byte, no?

can you help me please, how to get a BASE64 from onPreviewFrame?

thanks,